# "Cannot read property 'xxx' of null"

Tags: javascript, null, typeerror

I've got a document fragment with children that I want to loop over (when possible). This is causing an error "Cannot read property 'xxx' of null".

How do I test if this will be the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to do the following:

```
if ((documentFragment !== null) && documentFragment.hasOwnProperty('xxx')) {
    // handle property xxx of documentFragment as required
}
```

Comment: the second half of this test is throwing me an error... if ((documentFragment.firstChild !== null) && (documentFragment.firstChild.hasOwnProperty('tagName'))

Comment: @Matrym: Can you try doing `alert(typeof documentFragment);`. Do you get `object` or `undefined`?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: @Matrym: Oops... I had a missing/extra parenthesis. Check the updated answer.