# Breeze: Cannot read property 'xxx' of null?

Tags: breeze

I understand there are a few similar questions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711843/cannot-read-property-xxx-of-null)), but they all seem to be in different context. This is what I see in my chrome console:

```
Unhandled rejection reasons (should be empty): 
["TypeError: Cannot read property 'compound' of null…://localhost:1476/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:234:15)", joinBy: function, equals: function, indexByKey: function, getByKey: function, sortOn: function]
```

I could see this error in my debugger at failed(error):

```
   return manager.executeQuery(query).then(succeeded).fail(failed);

    function failed(error) {
        logger.logError(error);
    }
```

For a specific object, it happens most of time, but no always (maybe one out of 10 is okay). The query from server returns without exception. As I figured, it seems to be related to the query with a specific include of table. However, in fact, in this case, the included table doesn't have any related entry yet (if there is an entry, it doesn't seem to have any problem). Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the query and how the specific object you're referring to looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I accidentally found out what has caused this error. It is metadatastore post-construction initializer like

```
    manager.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor("Result", Result, initialize);
    // constructor
    function Result() {
    }
    // post-construction initializer
    function initialize(result) {
        result.cmpName = result.cs.compound.name;
    }
```

where result.cs could be null sometimes.
Too bad the error message didn't provide any clue.