# check if JSON object exist in sessionstorage javascript

Tags: javascript, json, session, session-variables

I am working on a site where some data is stored in the session. On the first page I need to check if the json object is already in the session. 
This is the code that fails.

```
 var passedTotaal = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('test totaal array'));
 if(passedTotaal.hasOwnProperty('letterplaatnaam')){
 //do something
 }
```

When the JSON object exist it works else I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null

I know this is because its empty.
I have looked at different stackoverflow questions but i couldn't find an answer
If there is any need for more information please let me know.

Comment: check null before checking hasOwnProperty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cannot read property 'xxx' of null"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711843/cannot-read-property-xxx-of-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if(passedTotaal!=null && passedTotaal.hasOwnProperty('letterplaatnaam'))
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = sessionStorage.getItem('test totaal array');
if (test) {
    var passedTotaal = JSON.parse(test);
    if(passedTotaal && passedTotaal.hasOwnProperty('letterplaatnaam')){
        //do something
    }
}
```

because getItem can return null as well